# CVXR: not recognizing a convex function

Tags: r, cvx

I am trying to do some quadratic optimization with linear constraints, using `CVXR`.
I have the following matrix in `R`:

```
HL <- matrix(c(
        s[2]*sqp[2]*sqq[2],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,s[3]*sqp[3]*sqq[3],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,s[4]*sqp[4]*sqq[4],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,s[1]*sqp[1]*sqq[1],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,s[3]*sqp[3]*sqq[3],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,s[4]*sqp[4]*sqq[4],0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,s[1]*sqp[1]*sqq[1],0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,s[2]*sqp[2]*sqq[2],0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,s[4]*sqp[4]*sqq[4],0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,s[1]*sqp[1]*sqq[1],0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,s[2]*sqp[2]*sqq[2],0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,s[3]*sqp[3]*sqq[3]
        ), nrow = num_vars, ncol = num_vars);
```

Then, I try to construct a `DCP` Ruleset-complying form:
by first defining `x = Variable(num_vars)`, and then writing
`fnc <- t(x) %*% HL %*% HL %*% x`, or even something like `y <- HL%*%x`,
and `fnc <- t(y)%*%y`. According to [DCP Ruleset](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#quadforms) (see Quadratic forms section), this should be recognized as convex. However, when I load
my source code into `R`, I get

> Forming a non-convex expression (affine) * (affine)

How to fix this? I need `CVXR` to be able to recognize my function as "following DCP rules".

Comment: try `fnc <- quad_form(x, HL %*% HL)`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, this solved it. Thank you. +1